# RoR: can't update a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, partial-views, put

I try to create a partial with an update form for one of my models, but when I run the server and browse the page with the partial I get a strange exception:

```
NoMethodError in Simpadmin/transactions#index

Showing /home/ben/proj/Simplee/master/app/views/simpadmin/transactions/_transaction_actions.html.haml where line #17 raised:

undefined method `payments_transaction_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000007bf1768>:0x00000007bceb00>
Extracted source (around line #17):

14:   %span.refund-success= flash[:refund_success]
15: 
16: .refund-edit
17:   = form_for transaction do |refund_form|
18:     .refund-reason
19:       = refund_form.label(:refund_reason, "Reason for refund:")
20:       = select_tag(:refund_reason, options_for_select(possible_refund_emails), :class => 'refund-reason-select') 
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/simpadmin/transactions/_

item.html.haml, app/views/simpadmin/transactions/index.html.haml
```

Maybe something is wrong with my routs (?)
Should I change something in the partial itself??

EDIT: The routes weren't written by me. anyway, here is the transaction's routes part:

```
 resources :transactions, :only => [:index, :update, :show] do                                                        
155       collection do                                                                                                      
156         get :export                                                                                                      
157         post :edit_cashed_checks                                                                                         
158         put :update_cashed_checks                                                                                        
159       end                                                                                                                
160       member do                                                                                                          
161         match :update_payee, :via => [:post, :put]                                                                       
162         match :add_comment, :via => :post                                                                                
163         put :refund                                                                                                      
164       end                                                                                                                
165     end
```

Comment: lets know routes file content pls...

Comment: The problem with the routing, sure

Comment: As Sush said, the routes would be helpful now. And it would be good to know what class the `transaction` object is. I suspect `PaymentTransaction`.

Comment: I have just edited my question and added the routes part.
The class is Payments::Transaction

Comment: @Sush, Now that the routes are here... do you have ant idea?
(@RyanBigg) (@SaidKaldybaev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the form_for and passing object of some model, in such cases rails implicitly assume the action to be invoked using the helper routine. Rails uses xyzs_path helper to find out the matching route, where Xyz is the model name whose object we are passing to form_for. It means there should be

```
 resources :xyzs
```

or

matching named route

```
 match 'some_url' => 'some_controller#action', :as => 'xyzs'
```

in your case, you need to define

```
 resources :payments_transaction
```

or

named route

```
 match 'some_url' => 'some_controller#action', :as => 'payments_transaction'
```

Comment: probably, you should use
 namespace :payments do
  resources :transactions
 end

Comment: glad, it helped :), actually I was looking for this, but your  question drove me towards the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the route for this form. You must define it like this in your routes file:

```
resources :payments do
  resources :transactions
end
```

For more information please see the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org).